# Spark AR Target Tracker

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to keep the effects turned on, even after the target is not visible any more?  I am using Spark AR Studio and I am able to successfully look at a target image and start the effects.  But when the image is removed from facebook camera view, the effects stop!  Is there a way to keep on showing the effects?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your file structure - what is the effect, and is it inside of the target tracker?

Comment: Yeah it is inside the target tracker.  Actually, it has worked.  I was moving the camera too fast for it to keep showing the effects! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the position of the object.

this keeps it in the scene and also keeps the effect.